# Where I can find some good UI templates to style my application?

Tags: templates, gwt, user-interface, graphics, themes

I'm developing a GWT application and I'd like to make it look good.
Since I'm not a graphic designer I think I'm going to look for a user interface template and replicate it in GWT using CSS.
For example I like the theme of ExtJS/ExtGWT a lot, but I don't think I can replicate the graphics due to licence restrictions.
Anyone has any idea where to look for some themes I can use without getting in trouble?

P.S.: I don't like built-in GWT themes.

Comment: try this http://gwt-theme-generator.appspot.com/ you can create your own themes

Answer (score 2):

You can look at [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/). There are 2 existing port in GWT :

- http://gwtbootstrap.github.io/
- http://nyao.github.io/bootstrap4gwt/